# i got an error while printing a particular symbol definite times (python)

Tags: python

```
sym = input("Enter the symbol : ")
name = input("Enter the number of times : ") 
print(sym* name)
```

I am getting an error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Answer (score 0):

If you want sym to be printed some definite number of times, then you should do explicit type conversion of second variable to an integer.

```
sym = input("Enter the symbol : ")
name = int(input("Enter the number of times : "))
print(sym* name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sym = input("Enter the symbol : ")
name = int(input("Enter the number of times : "))
print(str(sym) * int(name))
```